# How is it possible to run VLC when I just removed it?

Tags: linux-mint, vlc

After starting up my Linux Mint live session from hibernation, vlc would no longer start. When I tried running it from the terminal, I got a 'Bus error'. So I then tried to remove it.

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo apt-get purge vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  vlc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 367 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,690 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 171238 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing vlc (2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for vlc (2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) ...
```

But afterwards I can still run vlc (even though it comes up with the error)

```
mint@mint ~ $ vlc
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
Bus error
```

I will just reboot to make VLC work again, but I am confused about how it is possible to run VLC after it is removed. Shouldn't it say something like "No such file or directory"?

Comment: Type `which vlc` or similar to see what binary you are trying to run. As @dhag says, it is probably a local installation. (Apparently the cognoscenti don't quite approve of `which` for this purpose, but I don't remember why.)

Comment: @FaheemMitha, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=why+not+use+which&l=1 (sorry).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to purge `vlc-nox` as well:

```
apt-get purge vlc-nox
```

In general to find out where a file comes from, `dpkg -S` comes in handy; in this instance you'd run

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/vlc
```

Comment: Good catch, that's probably it :).

Comment: It worked, thanks! But what about the line `Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) ...` It doesn't mean that vlc-nox package is removed?

Comment: Also, if I now install vlc again, it will install vlc-nox with it. Is there any way to remove all packages, that came with given a package?

Comment: I'd have to investigate the triggers line further to answer your question; although you can be sure that if it finishes without error, once `apt-get purge vlc-nox` has finished then `vlc-nox` is really gone. To remove packages which are auto-installed (as dependencies), you can run `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: @plokijuh Triggers are a way for one package to be "notified" when another package is installed/removed. So that processing triggers line just means it was notified. Technical details @ http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/1.17.25/doc/triggers.txt/

Comment: Cool. But after removing both packages, I still get hundreds of results with `locate vlc`. And if I for instance type `dpkg -S /usr/share/vlc/vlc.ico`, I'm told it is in a package called vlc-data. Shouldn't I expect that to be removed too? Or how do I make a thorough uninstallation?

Comment: The results of `locate vlc` reflect the contents of the `locate` database, not the current filesystem contents; you need to run `updatedb` to get accurate results. If `apt-get autoremove` didn't remove everything you'll need to explore the list of packages manually; start with `dpkg -l | grep vlc | grep ^ii`.

Comment: You can also try `deborphan` or `debfoster` to identify unnecessary packages.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess would be that you had more than one copy of VLC installed. `apt-get purge` removed the system-wide copy, but will have left any other that may be in your path. You could use the command `which vlc` to get a full path.

Comment: It just says `/usr/bin/vlc`. How do I remove the other copy? If I try the purge command again, it will tell me that it is not installed.

Comment: It would be best to know first how that copy that apt-get doesn't know about got installed, but you can simply run `rm /usr/bin/vlc` as root (e.g., with sudo).

Comment: @dhag is that safe? Surely that leaves other related files? Or does `autoremove` clean them up?

Comment: vlc was just preinstalled in the distro. Am I correct to assume that if I type `sudo apt-get install vlc` without removing the existing version, it should automatically remove the old version and install the newest?

Comment: Yes, `apt-get install` installs the most acceptable version (generally speaking, the latest), or upgrades it if the package is already installed and not the most acceptable.

Comment: I believe `install` will just upgrade; but in any case I'm pretty sure Stephen's answer is the right one: the package is called `vlc-nox`.